# "Unload" lazy loaded entities

Tags: database, jpa, lazy-loading

i have an application with a derby database and use eclipselink as the persistence api.
Say i have a gui with a list of teams. Each team has a number of players on it. The relationship in the team class looks like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List<player> players = new ArrayList<player>():
```

and the player class like this:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Team.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "teamID", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "ID")
private Team team;
```

So i now start my application and it fills a list with all existing teams:

```
public List<Team> getTeams()
{
    TypedQuery<Team> query = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Team t",  Team.class);
    List<Team> teams = query.getResultList();
    return teams;
}
```

All is working right so far, only the teams are loaded, not the players. Say i now open a table with the players of a team by selecting a team and exectue the command for this. The table is filled with:

```
team.getPlayers();
```

So now all the players of this team are loaded, cause they are now needed.
But after i close the table they remain loaded, but i would like to "unload" them again so that they don't remain in memory - how would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of managed entities from its context you can call `EntityManager.clear()` method (calling `EntityManager.flush()` before). This operation, however, removes **all** managed entities, which is not necessarily what you want, since this might cause additional database hits.

If you are lucky and you can use JPA 2.0 there is a better option: `EntityManager.detach(Object)` method, which is removing given object from persistence context.